# How can I get multiple query string from URL when redirecting in IIS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm adding some URL rewrite rules on my IIS so it redirects an old URL to a new location.

It works when the URL has only one query string parameter, but if I have more than one it does not work. Is there anything I can do so I can get the second parameter if it exists and if not just get the first one?

Here is my web.config rule.

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1 for viewtopic.php" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^.*(?:viewtopic.php).*$.*" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^t=/name=([0-9]*)/" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/view/{C:1}/topic" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

The rule will work if my URL is like this. https://example.com/viewtopic.php?t=123456

Now I do have some old URLs that is formatted like this https://example.com/viewtopic.php?t=123456&highlight=Welcome

in this case when the IIS rule runs it gives me the following redirect URL
https://example.com/view/123456&highlight=Welcome/topic and I'm trying to make the URL to be like this: https://example.com/view/123456/topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule.

It will only match the first query string value.

```
            <rule name="MultipleQueryStringRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^.*(?:viewtopic.php).*$.*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^t=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/view/{C:1}/topic" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```